# Solving equation using bodmas in C#

Tags: c#

I have equations like `(7+((8%2)(7%3)))`. I want to solve this using bod-mas: first brackets should be solved after it divide, multiple, addition and subtraction.

I have the program in which the user creates a formula using salary heads like basic pay, etc. After that I find their value like the equation above and now I want to solve it.

I visited http://www.codeproject.com; they gave a solution like:

```
string equationString = "(7+((8%2)(7%3)))";
string explicitMultiply = equation String.Replace(")(", ")*(");
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Maybe you mean [how to parse math expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net) (assuming [bodmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BODMAS) means order of operations)?

Comment: The OP is really asking about implicit multiplication. This is an interesting question. The silent downvotes and the inept editing are unfortunate, but typical of SO.

Comment: You're making a whole lot of assumptions about what's being asked, especially considering that there's a thread implying `%` is intended to be a "percentage of" operator.

Comment: The CodeProject project that is (badly) linked to seems to try to solve the implicit multiplication problem. There's nothing to indicate that the OP is after the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

C# has it [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx),

> ((8%2)(7%3)) //I tired but it is giving me an error Method Name
>   expected

This is the result

```
(8 % 2) //return 0
(7 +0 ) // returns 7
```

Finally

```
(7 + ((8 % 2)*(7 % 3)))  //return 7
```

Updates:

Your code is completely a string which will not be executed to return integer

```
string equationString = "(7+((8%2)(7%3)))";
 string explicitMultiply = equationString.Replace(")(", ")*(");
 Console.WriteLine(explicitMultiply);
```

> **returns (7 + ((8 % 2)*(7 % 3)))** as a string

Incase if you want to do an equation conversion like [**NCalc**](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) or [**FLEE**](http://flee.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home)

Also take a look at [**BODMAS principle in .NET**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941104/bodmas-principle-in-net)

Comment: but i want first the percentage of 8 that is 0.16 that multiple with 7%3 that will 0.21 and the answer will 7.0336

Comment: @RajbirSingh `(8 % 2)` returns 0 not 0.16.  check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Comment: @RajbirSingh The `%` operator in most programming languages is *modulus* (remainder after division), not *percentage*.  If you want it to read `8%2` as *8 percent of 2* then you have a lot of work ahead of you.

Comment: i know sir it returns the modules of 8%2 that is 0 but i want it must use like percentage

Comment: yes exotically  my problem to read it not as modules read it as percentage and the brackets to solve first

Comment: @RajbirSingh What do you mean by to do as percentage operation?  % in c# is modulus operator.  I'm not sure `8*100/10`

Answer (score 0):

You are really asking about implicit multiplication. The solution that you quote will not work for cases such as "7(3+4)". It will only work when there is a bracket on both sides of the implicit multiplication.

Implicit multiplication is difficult to implement in practice. The rule is saying that if parsing fails because an operator is missing, that a multiplication sign should be added.

The quoted solution is on the right lines, but incomplete.

Comment: i want the logic to solve first equitation between the brackets (7+((8*2)*(7*3))) that first 8*2 solve then 7*3 then both multiple like 16*21=336 and then 7 add

Comment: In that case you have two problems: parsing an algebraic expression, and implementing implicit multiplication. You need to start by finding an innermost bracket, and then proceeding recursively. An innermost bracket is spanned by a pair of bracket symbols that do not contain any other bracket symbols. In the example that you give, (8*2) is an innermost bracket.

Comment: This is not difficult. You just need to find the maximum depth to which any expression is nested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate that string, then you can use http://ncalc.codeplex.com/ which is a open source framework.

And also you can evaluate it using the method defined at

[Evaluating string "3*(4+2)" yield int 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-sharp-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)

Which is like :

```
    string equationString = "(7+((8%2)(7%3)))";
    string explicitMultiply = equationString.Replace(")(", ")*(");
    double f = Evaluate(explicitMultiply);

    static double Evaluate(string expression)
    {
        var loDataTable = new DataTable();
        var loDataColumn = new DataColumn("Eval", typeof(double), expression);
        loDataTable.Columns.Add(loDataColumn);
        loDataTable.Rows.Add(0);
        return (double)(loDataTable.Rows[0]["Eval"]);
    }
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: almost just one thing i want to now how can i replace (8%2) to (8*2/100) after this my problem will be solve

Comment: i have used string builder or replace method  but it does not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a two step process: first, you need to go through your string expression and replace '%' with '/ 100 *' and then you can you use Alexei's [how to parse math expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net).

Comment: thank you  sir it works. but when i operate this 3(4*2) it shows syntax error and how can i check the user input expression is in correct format

Comment: if i replace ( with '*(' then if i have equation like 3((482/100)*2) create problem please tell me if anyone have solution of it

Comment: Could you edit your original question and show us the code you have so far? More than likely, it's just a matter of tweaking the parsing of the string.